# Deleting element of Cloud FireStore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

On this page I do not  know how to get the ID of one card then:

```
import React from "react";
    import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

let id = "???"

export function TaskCard({ ri, ci, cards, navigation }) {
  function HandelTouch(id) {
    navigation.navigate("EditScreen", { id: id });
  }

  const days = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    const current_date = new Date();
    current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate() + i);
    const options = { weekday: "long" };
    const new_date = current_date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
    days.push(new_date.split(",")[0]);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {cards.map((card, index) => {
        const options = { weekday: "long" };
        const new_date = card.date
          .toDate()
          .toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
        let day = new_date.split(",")[0];

        if (day === days[0]) {
          day = 1;
        } else if (day === days[1]) {
          day = 2;
        } else if (day === days[2]) {
          day = 3;
        } else if (day === days[3]) {
          day = 4;
        } else if (day === days[4]) {
          day = 5;
        } else if (day === days[5]) {
          day = 6;
        } else if (day === days[6]) {
          day = 7;
        }

        let hour = card.hour;
        if (hour >= 6 && hour <= 12) {
          hour = hour - 5;
        } else if (hour >= 1 && hour <= 5) {
          hour = hour + 7;
        }

        return hour === ri && day === ci ? (
          <View key={`${index} ${ri}`} onTouchStart={HandelTouch()}>
            <Text>{card.title}</Text>
            <Text>{card.description}</Text>
          </View>
        ) : (
          <View key={`${index} ${ri}`} />
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: 90,
    height: 90,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderRadius: 10,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#000",
  },
  description: {
    fontSize: 15,
    color: "#000",
  },
});
```

then

```
import db from "../database/database";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { TextInput, Button } from "react-native-gesture-handler"; // Remove import for Button from "react-native-share"
import { useState } from "react";
import { updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { collection } from "firebase/firestore";
import { deleteDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

export function EditScreen({ id }) {
  const [state, SetState] = useState({
    title: "",
    description: "",
  });

  function SetData(k, v) {
    SetState({
      ...state,
      [k]: v,
    });
  }

  async function EditData(e) {
    await updateDoc(doc(db, "tasks", e), {
      title: state.title,
      description: state.description,
    });
  }

  async function DeleteData(e) {
    ???????
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Editar</Text>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="title"
        onChangeText={(val) => SetData("title", val)}
      ></TextInput>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="description"
        onChangeText={(val) => SetData("description", val)}
      ></TextInput>
      <Button title="Save" onPress={EditData}></Button> 
      <Button title="Delete" onPress={DeleteData}></Button> 
    </View>
  );
}
```

and how would I set up the async DeleteData function such that when I pass some id that element gets eliminated? and how would I stretch an ID from one element of my database, also IF I do get my ID am passing it correctly through here?

```
export function TaskCard({ ri, ci, cards, navigation }) {
  function HandelTouch(id) {
    navigation.navigate("EditScreen", { id: id });
  }
```

note I am passing navigation as prop from other component

Comment: I assume that EditData also doesn't work as intended?  What is the value of `e` that gets passed to it when it is invoked?  Also, what data is in each of the `cards` elements?

Comment: each cards element has a date,hour,title,description, e is the event

Comment: onTocuchStart is not doing nothung when I press the div

Comment: What is the value of `e` when EditData runs?